# Ajax Jquery File Uploader not working in IE11 & Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, internet-explorer-11

I have ajax jquery file uploader, it works fine in Chrome, Firefox but not working on IE and microsoft Edge.  it doesn't give me any response, i tried all possible solutions, and still not working..

here is my JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data)


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });

});
```

and my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file[]" type="file" required multiple />
  <input type="radio" name="something" value="1"> 1
  <input type="radio" name="something" value="2"> 2
</form>
```

How can be fix it!?

Comment: Do you see any **console errors**? in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the problem is with the way you are assigning `data` to your `ajax`. When you say `this` in `new FormData`, it actually refers this with `ajax call` and not with `form`. So better keep that concept outside and try again as below.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    //event.stopPropagation();//I don't think this is necessary
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata=new FormData($('form').get(0)) //try with this here
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formdata,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it just submitted and sent request POST to upload.php without any response!

Comment: @iOsam4h I think you really need to look into **[this post](https://blog.yorkxin.org/posts/2014/02/06/ajax-with-formdata-is-broken-on-ie10-ie11/)**